# Using localstorage in google amp

Tags: javascript, local-storage, amp-html

I have been trying to store some data on localStorage after response of a [amp-form](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-form/) using custom script (amp-script) in  form's [submit-success](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-form/#events) in an amp page.

According to [API compatibility table](https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom/blob/master/web_compat_table.md) by [amp.dev](https://amp.dev), Window.localStorage is allowed.

But I'm getting `Type must be specified` error in console by using amp-script

[image: type must be specified console error screenshot]

#### Code

```
<form
    method="post"
    target="_top"
    className="body"
    action-xhr={`//localhost:4000/check-user`}
    custom-validation-reporting="show-all-on-submit" >

    ----------------------
    ----- form inputs ----
    ----------------------

    <div className="success_message" submit-success="true">
        <amp-script width="200" height="50" script="store_data"></amp-script>
    
        <script id="store_data" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
            Window.localstorage.setItem("__t", randomGUID(19)); // randomGUID returns a random alphanumeric string of specified length
        </script>
    </div>

</form>
```

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: is the type is "text/plain" or "text/javascript"

Comment: type is "text/javascript" but a/c to [load-javascript-from-a-local-element](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/#load-javascript-from-a-local-element), specified js using type "text/plain"

Comment: did you added the meta tag as shown in the docs ?

Comment: yes, i 've added it in <head>

Comment: can you try to do it as in the docs, i see diff that in the question it is in between form tag, try executing outside or same like in the docs.

Comment: i'm getting same error even outside form, though i need to add the script inside form submit-success.

Comment: so if you repeat the same code in the docs also its not working is that what we can conclude

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS, yes